# Storing a B-Tree in a file

Tags: java, data-structures, tree, graph-algorithm, b-tree

I find many articles about b-tree but none helped me.

I want to store a B-tree on disc, but I don't want to serialize the tree object, I think that there is a way to save only the values of a tree in some order that after I can restore the tree again.

I tried store the values in some orders, like Pre-order, In-order (symmetric), Post-order, but when values are inserted again the tree changes.

The image below is an example of a b-tree that I want to store.

[image: B-tree example]

Image from http://slady.net/java/bt/view.php, B-Tree animation applet.

So, there is a way to save the structure of a tree with it's values?.

Comment: this is a long shot but maybe try and look here? https://github.com/jankotek/MapDB/tree/master/src/main/java/org/mapdb

Answer (score -1):

You're right that B-trees aren't meant to be serialized as a whole.  They're OK as an in-memory data structure, but most useful as an on-disk data structure where memory may be different (possibly only holding a single node in memory at a time).

For an example of Java code using a B-tree on disk and a subset of the nodes cached in memory, see the JDBM source code, one place to start might be https://github.com/jankotek/JDBM3/blob/master/src/main/java/org/apache/jdbm/BTreeNode.java#L831 .

Comment: This algorithm is complex, maybe the answer is there but I don't see.. could you explain the basic way to store the b-tree structure? I don't need to get few nodes lazying, I want only save the tree on file and restore the tree identically after.